# How can extract text from video stream?

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, orc

I'm traying to extract some text from video stream coming from my camera using opencv2 and pytesseract. I crop the image to get an other small image. I trayed different image processing to get it work. I inverted the image values, blur it, binarize it, but no one of these is working with tesseract. The data that I want to extract has these form 'float/float' here is example of the small image:

[image]

Seems like the characters are not separated and this is the maximum resolution that I can get from my camera. I tried then to filter by color, but no result because it is video and the background is always moving.
I will use any suggested Python module that can work.

Comment: Have you tried template matching for each character?

Comment: thank you Miki for responding, I'm at 25 frame/second is it possible to do template matching for each character one by one ? do i have to divide this small image to smaller images than compare ?

Comment: I cannot guarantee the framerate, but should be faster than any other OCR approach. You have 10 templates for the 10 digits, and probably 1 for the slash (and 1 for the point?). Then apply template matching 11 (12) times (with each template) on the whole image. You should be able to find the correct digit looking at the maximum values in the results of the matching...

Comment: hi mikki, the template matching in this situation is not working.

Answer (score 1):

not trivial as it seems. i generated 32x32 png image for every character and add a white noise to it. the backgound on the video is moving. and caracters like 8 and 6 are not very different.
here is my code for the moment:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp:...")
time.sleep(2)
templates = {}
w=[]
h=[]
for i in range(0,11):
    templates["template_"+str(i)]=cv2.imread(str(i)+'.bmp',0)
    tmp_w,tmp_h=templates["template_"+str(i)].shape[::-1]
    w.append(tmp_w)
    h.append(tmp_h)



threshold = 0.70



while(True):
    les_points=[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if frame==None:
      break
    crop_image=frame[38:70,11:364]
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(crop_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    for i in range(0,11):
        res= cv2.matchTemplate(gray,templates["template_"+str(i)],cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
        for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
            les_points[i].append(pt[0])
            cv2.rectangle(crop_image, pt, (pt[0] + w[i], pt[1] + h[i]), (0,i*10,255), 2)
    print les_points
    cv2.imshow('normal',crop_image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)& 0xFF == ord('p'):
        threshold=threshold+0.01
        print threshold
    if cv2.waitKey(1)& 0xFF == ord('m'):
        threshold=threshold-0.01
        print threshold
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

I'm doing other tests by split the image to the exact same size of the caracters in templates. but this is not giving good results